# Have to save a record in NestJs using TypeORM

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I have started to learn a NestJs and I need a little bit of help
In this case, I try to create a new record in the DB and for it, I use another logic other than documentation
In this case, I don't have any errors and the record in DB also save
But in DB the record has fields equal to null
This is my code

```
async create(userDto: UserDto) {
    try {
      const user = new User();
      await this.userRepository.save(user, {
        data: {
          firstName: userDto.firstName,
          lastName: userDto.lastName,
          email: userDto.email,
          phone: userDto.phone,
          password: userDto.password,
        },
        reload: true,
      });
      return {
        user: user,
        message: 'The new record created successfully',
        statusCode: HttpStatus.CREATED,
      };
    } catch (err) {
      throw err;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this

```
const user = this.userRepository.create({
          firstName: userDto.firstName,
          lastName: userDto.lastName,
          email: userDto.email,
          phone: userDto.phone,
          password: userDto.password,
        });

await this.userRepository.save(user,{reload: true})
```

Comment: This doesnt work for me, i have fetched the record using repository's findOne than made sure its there and updated the property and tried to save() the same way, but doesnt reflect in my db

Comment: Weird @YuvrajAgarkar, send me the code i might help you out

Comment: here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74068602/typeorm-update-method-doesnt-work-when-using-repository